# Unable to update react state from user input data

Tags: reactjs

```
  import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
  import "./App.css";


  export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        data: [
          {
            id: 1,
            Firstname: "Jill",
            Lastname: ["john", "hobss", "smith"],
            Age: [1, 2, 3],
            company: ["facebook", "google", "netflix"],
            skills: ["python", "java", "scala"]
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            Firstname: "Jill",
            Lastname: ["john", "hobss", "smith"],
            Age: [1, 2, 3],
            company: ["facebook", "google", "netflix"],
            skills: ["python", "java", "scala"]
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            Firstname: "Jill",
            Lastname: ["john", "hobss", "smith"],
            Age: [1, 2, 3],
            company: ["facebook", "google", "netflix"],
            skills: ["python", "java", "scala"]
          },
          {
            id:4,
            Firstname: "Jill",
            Lastname: ["john", "hobss", "smith"],
            Age: [1, 2, 3],
            company: ["facebook", "google", "netflix"],
            skills: ["python", "java", "scala"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }

    handleChange = (id, company, event) => {
      const data = this.state.data;
      for(let d of data){
        if(d.id === id){
          for(let c of d.company){
            if(c === company){
              c = event.target.value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }


    render() {
      return (
        <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
              <th>Firstname</th>
              <th>Lastname</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>company</th>
              <th>skills</th>
          </tr>
          {
            this.state.data.map(td => {
              return (
                <tr>
              <td>{td.Firstname}</td>
              <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>{td.Lastname[0]}</td>
                      <td>{td.Lastname[1]}</td>
                      <td>{td.Lastname[2]}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>{td.Age[0]}</td>
                      <td>{td.Age[1]}</td>
                      <td>{td.Age[2]}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" value={td.company[0]} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(td.id, td.company[0], e)} />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" value={td.company[1]} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(td.id, td.company[1], e)}/>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" value={td.company[2]} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(td.id, td.company[2], e)}/>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>{td.skills[0]}</td>
                      <td>{td.skills[0]}</td>
                      <td>{td.skills[0]}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
          </tr>
              )
            })
          }
        </table>
        </div>
      )
    }

  }
```

Here i am trying to update my table using input data .

I am sending data using event to handleChange() function and changing data of state.

But It is not working please have a look.

I am not able to change input value also.

Please have a look 
if any way to solve this issue.

Thanks

I am sending data using event to **handleChange()** function and changing data of state.

But It is not working please have a look.

I am not able to change input value also.

Please have a look 
if any way to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a https://CodeSandbox.io for this please?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-pike-7zxof

Comment: because you should use `setState` to let know react that you update the state and triggers the complete lifecycle... i'll try to update your code sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently mutating state which is an anit-pattern in react.  In order to update state you need to call `this.setState(newState)` which will then trigger your component to rerender with the new state values;

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the `value` attribute of the input with `defaultValue` so it can be changed in the first place, then use `setState` in your handleChange method to update the data.